# Runtime calculation in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need some advice on update statement to populate one column on the run for table. I am using mysql 5.6.25-. Please find below table and data scripts.

```
create table test (symbol varchar(2), sym_date date, amount int, diff_amt int PRIMARY KEY (symbol,sym_date)) engine=InnoDB;

insert into test(symbol,sym_date, amount) values('A','2015-07-01',200);
insert into test(symbol,sym_date, amount) values('A','2015-07-02',100);
insert into test(symbol,sym_date, amount) values('A','2015-07-03',500);
insert into test(symbol,sym_date, amount) values('A','2015-07-04',800);
insert into test(symbol,sym_date, amount) values('B','2015-07-03',300);
insert into test(symbol,sym_date, amount) values('B','2015-07-05',500);
insert into test(symbol,sym_date, amount) values('B','2015-07-06',600);
insert into test(symbol,sym_date, amount) values('C','2015-07-09',100);
insert into test(symbol,sym_date, amount) values('C','2015-07-11',100);
insert into test(symbol,sym_date, amount) values('C','2015-07-12',100);
```

I need difference for amount column between the result set based on symbol while symbol, sym_date in ascending order in remaining column diff_amt.

```
select symbol, sym_date, amount from test order by symbol, sym_date;

It will give me this result set.

symbol   sym_date      amount
----------------------------
A       2015-07-01      200
A       2015-07-02      100
A       2015-07-03      500
A       2015-07-04      800
B       2015-07-03      300
B       2015-07-05      500
B       2015-07-06      600
C       2015-07-09      100
C       2015-07-11      100
C       2015-07-12      100
```

I need diff_amt column to be populated as difference in result set. For each symbol, its first value will be same. Next row will be 2nd value - 1st value, which will give result r1. Next row will be 3rd value - r1 and contiue same.

```
Expected result set will be as below:

symbol   sym_date     amount   diff_amt
-------------------------------------------------
A       2015-07-01      200     200         -- (ar1 = A1)
A       2015-07-02      100     -100        -- (ar2 = A2 - ar1)
A       2015-07-03      500     600         -- (ar3 = A3 - ar2)
A       2015-07-04      800     200         -- (ar4 = A4 - ar3)
B       2015-07-03      300     300         -- (br1 = B1)
B       2015-07-05      500     200         -- (br2 = B2 - br1)
B       2015-07-06      600     400         -- (br3 = B3 - br2)
C       2015-07-09      100     100         -- (cr1 = C1)
C       2015-07-11      100     0           -- (cr2 = C2 - cr1)
C       2015-07-12      100     100         -- (cr3 = C3 - cr2)
```

This is just sample scenario. I am looking for general solution to apply for big table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using variables.  I think the following is the logic:

```
select t.*,
       (@val := if(@s = symbol, amount - @val,
                   if(@s := symbol, amount, amount)
                  )
       ) as diff_amount
from test t cross join
     (select @s := '', @val := 0) params
order by symbol, sym_date;
```